# firebase query on the second/third level

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Javascript with Firebase and I want to make a query on a value exist on the second or the third level, My DB is like that :

```
Users :
        -KNwBd5cF6iY9dWh0eFd :
                name: "Jon Snow"
                phones:
                    phone1: "0123456789"
                    phone2: "0123456987"
```

And I want to make a query on the `phone1` value, I am using `orderByChild` to query the DB for now and my code is :

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("users");
ref.orderByChild("name").equalTo("Jon Snow").on("value", function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

But I can only use it to query on the value of the first level of values but how to make another query on the second or third level.

Comment: If I got it, what you are trying to do is a [multiple where clauses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase), and this is a duplicate.

Comment: No, I don't want to make multiple wheres I just want make a query on the child of the child of the object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing the phone id and considering your current database structure this wont be possible.

One workaround is to use the actual phone number as the key in `/phones`.

```
{ 
  users:
    userId:
       phones:
          0123456789: true
}
```

Then you will be able to retrieve it with:

```
ref.orderByChild("phones/"+phoneNumber).equalTo(true).once("value", function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

Working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vyp76wj1/21/).

---

This would be simple if you had the `phoneId`.

```
ref.orderByChild("phones/phone1").equalTo("0123456789").once("value", function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

Since you don't, it turns to be a good example of how you should not be structuring a noSQL database.

noSQL databases are very flexible and its structure will depend pretty much on your application. So keep it in mind. If, for example, searching for a `phoneNumber` will be critical in your application and you want to have more data inside `/phones/phoneNumber/` you should consider having a new separate branch to handle this in a more dedicated manner than you are doing now.

Comment: Great answer Adolfo! Note that the answer you deleted was a great example of why OPs data model doesn't work. I'd recommend merging it into this answer with an explanation (one more reason why arrays are often a bad solution, especially when like this case the data is actually a set).

Comment: Hey @FrankvanPuffelen, we would have some indexation problem in this case right? Could it lead to performance problems?

Comment: You'd index need an index on each phone. For alternative data structure to work around that, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value